# Calculation of option Greek (sensitiviety) theta via finite difference

Tags: options, greeks, finite-difference-method

I am able to get good approximations for delta, gamma, and rho via finite difference method, but not theta.  I believe my issue is the value of h.  Theta is basically the difference between the price of the the option one time step in the future and the price today divided by the size of the time step, ie

theta (approx) = V(d_v+1) - V(d_v)/(1/365),
where V(d_v+1) is the value of the option one time step (1/365) into the future

This basically comes from http://docs.fincad.com/support/developerfunc/mathref/greeks.htm

If I apply this to, for example, the call option quote on 04/18/2013 for ticker A (Agilent, I believe), strike of 40, underlying price of 41.83, expiry of 05/18/2013 (30/365 days to maturity), 1.1% Dividend Yield, 0.3% risk-free rate, I get a theta of -8.9, whereas the actual theta is approximated by a large options data reporting firm as approx -2.2.  My other Greek approximations are close enough, but I cannot get a good approximation for theta.  Anybody have insight into this issue?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Volatility=... ?

Comment: you can use this function in matlab: [CallTheta, PutTheta] = blstheta(Price, Strike, Rate, Time,
Volatility, Yield) and compare solutions.

Comment: Sorry, Implied Vol = 0.3263.

Comment: Yes it is correct. blstheta(40,41.83,0.003,1/12,0.3263,0.011)

ans =

   -8.0890

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am really looking for the specific algo to calculate this (pseudocode). I am not really looking for a black box function for theta calculation, I am looking a reliable algo for theta calculation.  I am not convinced of the accuracy for this Matlab function which you are suggesting, nor am I convinced of the accuracy of my finite difference application to this calculation.  It is possible that this particular commercial vendor is incorrect, but I would like to definitively prove it by constructing my own algo, which would not be black-box (at least to me).

Comment: could you give us more details about this data reporting firm ? do you know what model they use to price their options ?

Comment: It is www.optiondata.net.  I have had extensive conversations with them, and they can only tell me that Binomial method was used.  I suspect that they are normalizing their theta and rho, so I think that the Matlab function that you referenced, as well as the finite difference methodology I have been using is actually about right.  For the record, using h = 1/365 seems to work best for finite difference method for theta.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is tricky. Try using second order finite differencing to account for convexity

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your data provider how exactly they come up with this number. Many implementations divide theta by 365 or some other yearly day count to arrive at "theta per day".

It should be simple enough to check the value: for a European option, you can use the analytic formula; for American Options, you can use a tree. Methods to get the Greeks in the binomial method are described in the paper [Implementing Binomial Trees](http://ssrn.com/abstract=1341181)